# Polar color mesh from 1d arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have three arrays

```
theta

array([180., 180., 180., 180., 180., 180., 180., 180., 180.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 225., 225., 225.,
       225., 225., 225., 225., 225., 225.,  45.,  45.,  45.,  45.,  45.,
        45.,  45.,  45.,  45.,  45., 270., 270., 270., 270., 270., 270.,
       270., 270., 270.,  90.,  90.,  90.,  90.,  90.,  90.,  90.,  90.,
        90.,  90., 315., 315., 315., 315., 315., 315., 315., 315., 315.,
       135., 135., 135., 135., 135., 135., 135., 135., 135., 135.])
```

```
phi

array([45.        , 39.98823529, 35.01176471, 30.        , 24.98823529,
       20.01176471, 15.        ,  9.98823529,  5.01176471,  0.        ,
        5.01176471,  9.98823529, 15.        , 20.01176471, 24.98823529,
       30.        , 35.01176471, 39.98823529, 45.        , 45.        ,
       39.98823529, 35.01176471, 30.        , 24.98823529, 20.01176471,
       15.        ,  9.98823529,  5.01176471,  0.        ,  5.01176471,
        9.98823529, 15.        , 20.01176471, 24.98823529, 30.        ,
       35.01176471, 39.98823529, 45.        , 45.        , 39.98823529,
       35.01176471, 30.        , 24.98823529, 20.01176471, 15.        ,
        9.98823529,  5.01176471,  0.        ,  5.01176471,  9.98823529,
       15.        , 20.01176471, 24.98823529, 30.        , 35.01176471,
       39.98823529, 45.        , 45.        , 39.98823529, 35.01176471,
       30.        , 24.98823529, 20.01176471, 15.        ,  9.98823529,
        5.01176471,  0.        ,  5.01176471,  9.98823529, 15.        ,
       20.01176471, 24.98823529, 30.        , 35.01176471, 39.98823529,
       45.        ])
```

```
violet_ints

array([ 60821.47285091,  71469.47778826,  81950.58139812,  92660.95741024,
       103228.07719577, 113446.6171393 , 123862.48451513, 132666.65201113,
       138673.94497866, 141418.87424494, 140947.68057807, 137704.80141046,
       131712.10023037, 122871.74227686, 111022.93897237,  98051.87876927,
        85884.71515151,  74789.81179595,  64223.21535332,  47239.6029958 ,
        59060.46569283,  71631.51992138,  85056.88727878,  97838.32318773,
       110985.04206186, 123046.60805235, 131994.74029036, 138009.81758468,
       141092.29699058, 141436.99265739, 139367.40863866, 134564.53259257,
       127256.22737589, 117476.56579378, 105893.78184852,  94434.79559289,
        83012.77977437,  71513.83906988,  35465.27768276,  52489.59008641,
        70259.4064192 ,  87011.24343702, 101845.51856053, 114496.37908394,
       125113.38041456, 132956.15831876, 138245.26502938, 140988.36471711,
       141467.04309028, 139302.73813352, 135346.73647267, 128688.98045284,
       120273.38645452, 110273.45442647,  99177.33744858,  87341.78739578,
        74874.97094334,  50986.33091372,  63371.63698099,  76937.62936534,
        91341.43206481, 105418.35862792, 117371.0063522 , 127397.07283259,
       134693.40421132, 139258.98685025, 141392.73492377, 140797.81487188,
       137360.21016255, 130967.39590833, 122385.40640793, 113290.91743172,
       103305.45203984,  93133.15852394,  82350.70121816,  71046.51493323])
```

I made a polar plot with these arrays

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
ax = plt.axes(projection='polar')
axx = ax.scatter(theta*np.pi/180, phi, c=violet_ints,
                                       cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar(axx, shrink = 0.4);
```

[Polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETuYM.png)

Now I want to interpolate these data so that I can get a color mesh plot like this one.

Interpolated plot:

[image: Interpolated plot]

I tried to convert my arrays into meshgrids

```
Theta, Phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
_, Violet_Ints = np.meshgrid(violet_ints, violet_ints)
```

However when I try to make a plot using pcolormesh, it does not make sense

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
ax = plt.axes(projection='polar')

ax.pcolormesh(Theta*np.pi/180, Phi, Violet_Ints,
                                       cmap='viridis');
```

My attempt to plot meshgrid:

[image: My attempt to plot meshgrid]

Can you guys help me with this one, please?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you're missing is that `pcolormesh` attempts to interpolate between adjacent values. This means that the sortedness of your data is important. Once you fix that, you'll need to do a little `numpy` to ensure you satisfy the coordinate system that `.pcolormesh` needs.

Using your variables from above:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



theta = np.radians(theta)
idx = np.argsort(theta)
theta, phi, violet_ints = theta[idx], phi[idx], violet_ints[idx] # reroder data according to theta
theta_g, phi_g = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)                         # coordinates of theta/pho
_, violet_g = np.meshgrid(violet_ints, violet_ints)              # tile violet to align on coordinate grid
theta_g = np.hstack([theta_g, theta_g[:, [0]]])                  # append a column that is same as the first
phi_g   = np.hstack([phi_g,     phi_g[:, [0]]])

mosaic = [
    ['scatter', '.'      ],
    ['flat',    'gouraud'],
]
fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    mosaic, figsize=(15, 15), subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, gridspec_kw={'hspace': .5}
)

# plot scatter
axd['scatter'].scatter(theta, phi, c=violet_ints, cmap='viridis')
axd['scatter'].set_title('Scatter', size='xx-large', loc='left')

# plot "Flat Shading" pcolormesh
violet_g_flat = violet_g[:-1, :]
axd['flat'].pcolormesh(theta_g, phi_g, violet_g_flat, cmap='viridis', shading='flat');
axd['flat'].set_title('Flat Shading', loc='left', size='xx-large')

# plot "Gouraud Shading" pcolormesh
#   note that we use the same trick to "wrap" out colors
violet_g_gouraud = np.hstack([violet_g, violet_g[:, [0]]])
axd['gouraud'].pcolormesh(theta_g, phi_g, violet_g_gouraud, cmap='viridis', shading='gouraud');
axd['gouraud'].set_title('Gouraud Shading', loc='left', size='xx-large')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very helpful. I assume that there is averaging across each `phi` happening somewhere in your script and because of that it is impossible to see asymmetry in my data (for example at `phi=10 deg`). Is there a way to rectify it?